# Install towel warmer on a thermostat

Tags: thermostat, heater, bathroom-fixtures

I am considering   purchasing this towel warmer   [Model AN-5309](https://anconahome.com/products/comfort-dual-6-bar-hardwired-and-plug-in-towel-warmer-in-polished-stainless-steel)   for my bathroom.

I am setup to hard wire the device. I would like to attach this to a programmable wall thermostat.

Can anyone confirm if that is possible with this unit?

Comment: Is your programmable thermostat capable of switching line voltage?  the towel bar only draws .67 amps this is a small load but many thermostats are not rated for line voltage.

Comment: It's an Aube TH106 thermostat. On the back, it says: 120 / 240 VAC (60HZ). Minimum load 2 A. Does it imply this thermostat is not compatible?

Comment: That thermostat states a minimum 2 amp load so this device would not work. Some electronic switches require a load to function properly this must be one. I have a very similar towel bar it doesn't require a thermostat but if you want to save some power you could put it on a timer I use an intermatic ST01 it fits in a single gang receptacle I use these for several things around the house ok

Comment: Why do you want it on thermostat, **Wouldn't a timer be better solution?**  Turn it on when you get in the shower and you do not have to think to turn it off. A thermostat will keep it cycling on and off for  ALL the time you are not using it.

Comment: use the thermostat to control a relay which switches the power. An SSR would be better long-term and not click. Even better would be a triac dimmer that would throttle it to maintain the right temp without cycling. Best is using a fancy PID controller with bar and room temp sensors that can make dozens of adjustments per second to keep temp exactly as set.

Comment: Is there a reason you want the towel warmer burning power when nobody's home?

Comment: I originally wanted to get a some extra heat in the bathroom at specific times of day to top up the main heating system. I realize from the comments that using a thermostat is complicated in this case. The timer would be a better solution.